# Getting undefined from req.body

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

When i am dispatching startAddLike , I am getting undefined value of uid in the server side ie. req.body.uid = undefined.how to solve it?

Action generator:

```
export const startAddLike = (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const uid = getState().auth.uid;
        axios
            .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/${id}/like`, uid)
            .then(res => dispatch(likePost(id, uid)))
    }
}
```

Like Post Route

```
router.post('/:id/like', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.uid);
    Post.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, {$push: {likes: req.body.uid}},{ "new": true})
        .then(post => {
            console.log('l'+post);
            res.json(post);
        })
});
```

Comment: Do you use bodyParser module?

Comment: is `getState().auth.uid;` an Object?

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov yes, otherwise there would be an error, and not just `undefined`

Comment: @Sujoy, if you don't reply, we can't really help you

Comment: Yes. I have used body parser. It works fine when I am doing a post. But in this case, I am getting undefined from req.body.

Comment: @Luca kiebel yes. I am using firebase authentication here. And at first I was sending user ID directly from the component, then also I was getting undefined.

Comment: Can you console.log() uid?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It was night in my place. Yes. It returns correct uid in console

Comment: I have changed the console.log to (req.body) from (req.body.uid). Now the output is :.  { uid : ' '}. How does the value become key here?

Answer (score 0):

In here uid should be passed as an object.

So this should be

```
export const startAddLike = (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const uid = getState().auth.uid;
        axios
            .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts/${id}/like`, { uid: uid })
            .then(res => dispatch(likePost(id, uid)))
    }
}
```

Hope that fixes your issue.